# Not able to download anything from ubuntu terminal

Tags: software-installation, python3, ubuntu-minimal

I am new to Ubuntu and not well versed with its functioning. 
I was trying to upgrade my git version and a few other things but I am constantly getting an error as shown in the image below due to some python3.6 minimal or python3.6.

[image]

My Ubuntu version is 14.04 and a few days back I tried to upgrade my python version from 2.7 to 3.6 but I believe I failed as when I type python -V in terminal, I am still getting 2.7.2 and on typing python3 -V, its showing 3.6.0.

I believe the problem is something related to multiple versions. Please help me out.

Comment: That is not a problem, simply use the version of python you prefer. Get the variuos versions location with the `which python` and `which python3`

Comment: I prefer python3 . Can you tell me how can I make it my default version and delete the older one ??

Comment: You don't. Making `python` point to `python3` is just going to break things.